# I cannot use Shift-Alt- right click on Mac?

Tags: edges, shortcut, modeling

I have a problem using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>right click</kbd> in blender as it doesn't seem to work.

Is it to do with the Preference>Add on setting?

I have ticked the "emulate numberpad" and "3 button mouse."

[Edit]

[image]

The reason why I would want to use this shortcut is for selecting specific edges created by using Loop cut. Instead of going back to wireframe view to select the edges, which rather insufficient, I would like to select all the edges around an object.

Comment: What are you trying to do with Shift-Alt-R click? Keymapping right clicks on a Mac is a little funny because the OS has some native key strokes CMD+Click for right click that don't cooperate with Blender.

Comment: Hi there, I am trying to select a specific edges. I have post an image on this post.

Comment: I guess you are using R click select, is that correct? Shift-Alt-Select in edit mode should work to select multiple edges from loop cuts. I don't quite understand the problem.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find an answer?Would appreciate it if you share it with me .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you should choose to emulate 3 button modifier as os-key.